# Background CSS image disappears. Does not reappear until browser closes

Tags: html, css, background-image

I recently created a website, http://artemismoonlight.org. I have limited knowledge but enough to get me by. I use CSS to blur the background a little. This is the code I use.

This in the body:
`<div class="background-image"></div>`

And this in the CSS

```
.background-image {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;

    display: block;
    background-image: url('../assets/fcHouse2.png');
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;


    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(3px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(3px);
}
```

When you initially visit the page, the background may take a second or two to load but when changing page or refreshing, the background image might disappear and show this: http://puu.sh/mbH7d/fa4ac147d8.jpg

This doesn't happen 100% of the time but I still find it happening enough to me to make me wonder if others are getting this issue.

The image in question is only 261KB and I'm having this issue on Mozilla.

Comment: I'm in Firefox and cannot replicate your issue. I would think the design you're using with the `fixed` positioning should work.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an issue with your code. try what @Jay suggested.

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine for me in both Chrome and Firefox. Make sure you clear your cache or use incognito to make sure your css is updating.